# SQL Server index - very large table with where clause against a very small range of values - do I need an index for the where clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am designing a database with a single table for a special scenario I need to implement a solution for. The table will have several hundred million rows after a short time, but each row will be fairly compact. Even when there are a lot of rows, I need insert, update and select speeds to be nice and fast, so I need to choose the best indexes for the job.

My table looks like this:

```
create table dbo.Domain
(
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    MetricType smallint not null, -- very small range of values, maybe 10-20 at most
    Priority smallint not null, -- extremely small range of values, generally 1-4
    DateToProcess datetime not null,
    DateProcessed datetime null,

    primary key(Name, MetricType)
);
```

A select query will look like this:

```
select Name from Domain
where MetricType = @metricType
    and DateProcessed is null
    and DateToProcess < GETUTCDATE()
order by Priority desc, DateToProcess asc
```

The first type of update will look like this:

```
merge into Domain as target
using @myTablePrm as source
on source.Name = target.Name
    and source.MetricType = target.MetricType
when matched then
    update set
        DateToProcess = source.DateToProcess,
        Priority = source.Priority,
        DateProcessed = case -- set to null if DateToProcess is in the future
            when DateToProcess < DateProcessed then DateProcessed
            else null end
when not matched then
    insert (Name, MetricType, Priority, DateToProcess)
    values (source.Name, source.MetricType, source.Priority, source.DateToProcess);
```

The second type of update will look like this:

```
update Domain
set DateProcessed = source.DateProcessed
from @myTablePrm source
where Name = source.Name and MetricType = @metricType
```

**Are these the best indexes for optimal insert, update and select speed?**

```
-- for the order by clause in the select query
create index IX_Domain_PriorityQueue
    on Domain(Priority desc, DateToProcess asc)
    where DateProcessed is null;

-- for the where clause in the select query
create index IX_Domain_MetricType
    on Domain(MetricType asc);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observations:

- Your updates should use the PK
- Why not use tinyint (range 0-255) to make the rows even narrower?
- Do you need datetime? Can you use smalledatetime?

Ideas:

- Your SELECT query doesn't have an index to cover it. You need one on (`DateToProcess, MetricType, Priority DESC) INCLUDE (Name) WHERE DateProcessed IS NULL`
  `: you'll have to experiment with key column order to get the best one
- You could extent that index to have a filtered indexes per MetricType too (keeping DateProcessed IS NULL filter). I'd do this after the other one when I do have millions of rows to test with

Comment: Ah that is a good idea. Do you think it would make a seriously significant difference? The first run will probably stick about 150 million rows in the database, for what it's worth.

Comment: The second point - extending the filtered index to multiple indexes.

Comment: @NathanRidley: not yet. partitioning is also an option here instead of that: but 150m isn't that much. Wait until a lot more than that. Fix your datatypes too

Comment: Ok, great I think I have enough to go on, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your best performance will come from having no indexes on `Priority` and `MetricType`. The cardinality is likely too low for the indexes to do much good.

An index on `DateToProcess` will almost certainly help, as there is lilely to be high cardinality in that column and it is used in a `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause. I would start with that first.

Whether an index on `DateProcessed` will help is up for debate. That depends on what percentage of `NULL` values you expect for this column. Your best bet, as usual, is to examine the query plan with some real data.

Comment: So you think my first index should just be on DateToProcess and ignore Priority? I would have though it would cause the index to be pre-arranged in exactly the order I want it, which would give sql server less work to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the table schema section, you have highlighted that 'MetricType' is one of two Primary keys, therefore this should definately be indexed along with the Name column. As for the 'Priority' and 'DateToProcess' fields as these will be present in a where clause it can't hurt to have them indexed also but I don't recommend the where clause you have on that index of 'DateProcessed' is null, indexing just a set of the data is not a good idea, remove this and index the whole of both those columns.

Comment: The where clause on the index will prevent indexing of values that are explicitly excluded from the relevant query, which will keep the index size down and make it faster to scan and update.

Comment: Will there not be a future need for a query where 'DateProcessed' is not null, i'm just thinking ahead, if not then it's ok

Comment: No, this table is specifically for assisting with batch processing priority on a very large data set of data. The querying rules are pretty much set in stone already and if they were to change at any point, the table could in fact be blown away and still be rebuilt from the primary data source.

Comment: No worries, then yep those indexes should be fine, the PK's are where the greatest performance difference will be found